# Bash append values to a list inside a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following bash script sequence:

```
blocks=()

for line in ${fail_no[@]}
do
  new_line=`sed "$line!d" $1`
  command=`echo $new_line | cut -d ',' -f2`
  while [[ $new_line != *"$PROJ_NAME"* ]] 
  do
    line=$((line-1))
    new_line=`sed "$line!d" $1`
  done
  curr_block=`echo $new_line | cut -d ',' -f1`
  echo $curr_block
  blocks+=("$curr_block")
done

echo $blocks
```

Please ignore the details but I just want to add all the values of `curr_block` into the list `blocks`. When I run this script I have 2 values for `curr_block` but the `block` variable at the end contains only the value of the first `curr_block` and not the second one (or the one after that if is the case). I have been looking at this for 1h and I can't see where is the problem.

Comment: `echo "${blocks[@]}"`

Comment: Get your script checked at [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net).  Using $() is better than using backticks.  Also, you can use herestring `sed <<< "$new_line"` instead of `echo ... | sed ...`  to be more efficient.

Comment: `declare -p blocks` is a great way to print your array.

Comment: Repeatedly calling `sed` and `cut` like this is horribly inefficient. You can probably write a large chunk of this as a single `awk` script.

Comment: @chepner I agree, but unfortunately I'm not yet familiar enough with awk...is it on my list to learn though soon

Comment: What do you do with `command`? It doesn't appear to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`blocks` is an array. Using `echo $blocks` will print the first element (as you are seeing).

The correct way to print all elements of an array is as follows:

```
echo "${blocks[@]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
readarray -t blocks < <(
  awk -F, -v pname "$PROJ_NAME" '
      BEGIN { fail=('"${fail_no[*]}"'); }
      $0 ~ pname {block=$1};
      NR in fail { print $block; }
      ' "$1")
```

The single `awk` process goes through the file line by line, always remembering what the current value of `block` *will* be, should it encounter a line that matches one listed in `fail_no`. When it does, output that block. The output of `awk` is then collected in the desired array.